# How to get id of controls within UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

As I'm new in asp.net development and this could be a silly question but I'm asking this question here.

Id of controls like button, textbox in update panel is not visible in client side debugger
and if I write document.getelementbyid it gives me null value of the id of controls within updatePanel.

Actually My requirement is I want to write some javascript functions and in those functions I want to use the ids of controls.

So please guide me.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button control must be nested inside some parent controls.So for accessing that control you should use `ClientId` property of control because the ID generated in the final HTML is not guaranteed to remain the same.So it's recommended to use `ClientId` by considering future changes i.e. it might happen that the control might move in some other containers.
Refer below example:

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").value
```

Answer (score 1):

The .net controls that have runat="server" lives in the server. The id you assign to it can not be used in client side(JavaScript, Jquery ). What you can do is to assign a css class to that control and use Jquery to find that element.

For example :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCopy" CssClass="btnCopy" runat="server"  Text="Copy" />


 $('.btnCopy').click(function (evt) {

                //Javascript code

        });
```

this will get you the on click event of the server button.

You can grape the control and do what ever you want with it.

Example :

```
var button =   $('.btnCopy');
```

// do what ever you want with the button.